# How to install various compression codecs like LZO and BROTLI on pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, compression, lzo, brotli

For writing a parquet file and compressing it with LZO codec, I wrote the following code -

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("compression","lzo").option("header","true").parquet("PARQUET.parquet")
```

But, I am getting this error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lzo.LzoCodec
```

According to the spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html), brotli requires BrotliCodec to be installed. But there are no steps given to install it.
The same error is given while compressing with Brotli codec.

How can I install/add the required codecs for running it on PySpark ?

---

**EDIT** - LZO compression works with ORC but not with Parquet

Comment: if you are using Java/Scala , then you can add the jars directly using --jars option.
if you are writing in python then you will need to make sure your jar is available on the all the directory which is being used spark.jars (you can get this info from spark ui)

Comment: @AdityaVikramSingh which libraries should I download/install to get the required compression codecs ?

Comment: What is the spark version and jvm version you are using @Techie baba

Comment: Spark- 3.2.0, JVM - 8 @AdityaVikramSingh

Answer (score 1):

For writing in lzo, you need the below steps:

- `sudo apt-get install -y lzop`
- Add jar to pyspark jars(change path according to your pyspark env):  `wget https://maven.twttr.com/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.20/hadoop-lzo-0.4.20.jar -P /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/jars/`
- set this config option in SparkSession, `("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "lzo")`

Now you should be able to write using parquet with `lzo` compression.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jar files to `<python environment name>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars`