# Unexpectedly big parquet file size in Pyspark after sorting

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a 600Mb .CSV file with 6,5M rows and 10 columns. The columns are mostly ids and sums, but one column "type" has only 2 unique values: "online" and "offline".
When I read the file and save it as parquet (without any processing) it has around 60Mb, but when I read the file, sort by "type" and some ID, and then save it as parquet, the file size is around 300Mb.

Logically thinking, it should be smaller because it's easy to compress the sorted column "type" - something like "first 3,25M are offline, and next 3,25M are online". So the result is really surprising.

The environment:
Windows 10
Spark and Pyspark version: 3.4.1
Hadoop version: 3.0.0
Java: v8, 1.8.0_391-b13

So, why sorting has a negative effect on file size, and how to fix that?

UPD:

I have tested some codecs and techniques proposed by @mamonu and here are the results:

| Dataframe | Uncompressed | lz4 | gzip | snappy | zstd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| df | 224Mb | 77Mb | 195Mb | 82Mb | 67Mb |
| df with orderBy | 373Mb | 305Mb | 195Mb | 291Mb | 189Mb |
| df with repartitionByRange | 373Mb | 305Mb | 195Mb | 291Mb | 189Mb |

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to try out:
When saving a parquet file in Spark you are by default using
the `snappy` compression method. This has certain advantages but also certain disadvantages (see table below). Its not the most space saving efficient method.

```
df.write.parquet('file_snappy.parquet') #equivalent to the below
df.write.option('compression', 'snappy').parquet('file_snappy.parquet')
```

However there are [other compression methods](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Compression.md) you can try:
I would suggest you try all the below and check which one is the one that is smaller (note: some like [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) need installing of the codec. Which seems to be [not so straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850470/how-to-install-various-compression-codecs-like-lzo-and-brotli-on-pyspark)). However getting a jar file out of [here](https://github.com/rdblue/brotli-codec) and including it with conf.SparkJars might help.

```
df.write.option('compression', 'gzip').parquet('file_gzip.parquet')
df.write.option('compression', 'brotli').parquet('file_brotli.parquet')
df.write.option('compression', 'lz4').parquet('file_lz4.parquet')
df.write.option('compression', 'zstd').parquet('file_zstd.parquet')
```

You can use `spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec` to set a method of compression globaly once you decide which one is the best for you as per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#configuration)

As a guide this table might help. From what it seems brotli would be useful for your usecase if you manage to install it/get it working!
[image: compression codec comparison]

Apart from the codecs you could try to sort in a way that might be beneficial. There is some documentation for efficient and useful sorting in Spark. I would suggest having a look at `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` , `sortWithinPartitions` and others in the appropriate [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sortWithinPartitions.html). An example of using `sortWithinPartitions` after repartitioning by type and the id is below. Perhaps this will help(or not). By trying out different things you will find the best solution for your particular data.

```
repartitioned_sorted_df = df.repartitionByRange('type', 'id') \
                             .sortWithinPartitions(['type', 'id'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the repartitionByRange with sortWihtinPartitions has the same effect as OrderBy when you save a parquet file and bloats the file size.